itextPDF 8 to generate pdf with emoji font support
I'm trying to find out a way to create pdf with emoji fonts support by using itextpdf 8.0.3.
I only found an example that came from itextpdf official website; https://kb.itextpdf.com/itext/pdfhtml-using-emojis-in-itext but it is talking about create pdf from html source.
I found an other example on Internet such as: https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-display-emoji-in-a-pdf-document-using-itext-8/.
There are some code as:
package org.kodejava.itext;

import com.itextpdf.io.font.PdfEncodings;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.colors.DeviceRgb;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;

import java.io.IOException;

public class DocumentWithEmoji {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("emoji.pdf");
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

    try (Document document = new Document(pdf)) {
        PdfFont fontEmoji = PdfFontFactory.createFont("seguiemj.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);

        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph()
                .add(new Paragraph("Hello ").setFont(fontEmoji).setFontSize(20))
                .add(new Paragraph("\uD83D\uDE00").setFont(fontEmoji).setFontSize(20)
                        .setFontColor(new DeviceRgb(243, 58, 106)));

        document.add(paragraph);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

expected return should be:

but I got it as:

As you can see, it shows as red round dish instead of a red smile face.
Does anyone have such experience? if you do, please share some idea with me.

Please make sure that you have the seguiemj.ttf font under the src/main/resources directory in your Maven project. Different font might give you a different result.

My development environment is MacOS, production environment is Rocky Linux 9. Font was put into correct directory.

Color emojis are not supported by default in PDF files. With the code you use you will get the monochrome version of the emoji, assuming the font file includes the corresponding emoji. For color emojis you have to use a library that can convert the color emojis to Type3 fonts and then you use the Type3 font to display the color emoji.

@iPDFdev, thank you for your advice. I will do some more research about Type 3 fonts and itext PDF.

Can you post a link to output PDF file to take a look?


Project Directory
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── example
        │           └── itext
        │               └── DocumentWithEmoji.java
        ├── lib-jar-itext
        │   ├── barcodes-8.0.4.jar
        │   ├── bouncy-castle-adapter-8.0.4.jar
        │   ├── bouncy-castle-connector-8.0.4.jar
        │   ├── bouncy-castle-fips-adapter-8.0.4.jar
        │   ├── commons-8.0.4.jar
        │   ├── font-asian-8.0.4.jar
        │   ├── forms-8.0.4.jar
        │   ├── hyph-8.0.4.jar
        │   ├── io-8.0.4.jar
        │   ├── kernel-8.0.4.jar
        │   ├── layout-8.0.4.jar
        │   ├── pdfa-8.0.4.jar
        │   ├── pdftest-8.0.4.jar
        │   ├── pdfua-8.0.4.jar
        │   ├── sign-8.0.4.jar
        │   ├── styled-xml-parser-8.0.4.jar
        │   └── svg-8.0.4.jar
        └── resources
            └── fonts
                └── NotoEmoji-SemiBold.ttf

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.itext</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext8-emoji-fonts</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>itext8-emoji-fonts</name>
    <description>itext8-emoji-fonts</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>barcodes</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/barcodes-8.0.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>bouncy-castle-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/bouncy-castle-adapter-8.0.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>bouncy-castle-connector</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/bouncy-castle-connector-8.0.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>bouncy-castle-fips-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/bouncy-castle-fips-adapter-8.0.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/commons-8.0.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-asian</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/font-asian-8.0.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/forms-8.0.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>hyph</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/hyph-8.0.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>io</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/io-8.0.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/kernel-8.0.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/layout-8.0.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/pdfa-8.0.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfua</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/pdfua-8.0.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>sign</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/sign-8.0.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>styled-xml-parser</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/styled-xml-parser-8.0.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>svg</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/svg-8.0.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

DocumentWithEmoji.java
COPY AND MODIFY FROM YOUR EXAMPLE CODE
package com.example.itext;

import com.itextpdf.io.font.PdfEncodings;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.colors.DeviceRgb;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class DocumentWithEmoji {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("emoji.pdf");
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

        try (Document document = new Document(pdf)) {
            //PdfFont fontEmoji = PdfFontFactory.createFont("seguiemj.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
            PdfFont fontEmoji = PdfFontFactory.createFont("fonts/NotoEmoji-SemiBold.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);

            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph()
                    .add(new Paragraph("Hello "))
                    .add(new Paragraph("\uD83D\uDE00").setFont(fontEmoji).setFontSize(20)
                            .setFontColor(new DeviceRgb(243, 58, 106)));

            document.add(paragraph);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} 

NOTE
I only changed the font from seguiemj.ttf to NotoEmoji-SemiBold.ttf
Download Fonts - NotoEmoji-SemiBold.ttf
Download Noto_Emoji.zip from https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Emoji
Select , and Download All(1)
Unzip Noto_Emoji.zip ,
Noto_Emoji
├── NotoEmoji-VariableFont_wght.ttf
├── OFL.txt
├── README.txt
└── static
    ├── NotoEmoji-Bold.ttf
    ├── NotoEmoji-Light.ttf
    ├── NotoEmoji-Medium.ttf
    ├── NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf
    └── NotoEmoji-SemiBold.ttf

copy NotoEmoji-SemiBold.ttf to Project Directory: src/main/resources/fonts/
itext 8 jar
open https://github.com/itext/itext-java/releases/tag/8.0.4
download iText-Core-8.0.4-only-jars.zip
unzip iText-Core-8.0.4-only-jars.zip
put all jar to src/main/lib-jar-itext
I Test it in Idea.


Thank you for your response. I will test your code in my RND environment and update you.
